# Kendo Window Declared in HTML How to Open?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid that I have created using the HTML-based declarative syntax

```
<div id="grid-view"
    data-role="grid"
    data-height="700"
    data-selectable="single"
    data-rowTemplate="mn-grid-row"
    data-pageable="true"
    data-pagesize="5"
         <!-- etc--->
     ></div>
```

I want to declare a Kendo Window that creates a filter for a field not shown in the grid. I would like to declare the window in the same way. It would be bound to the same VM as the grid. I am just not sure how I would control the open functionality or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the same that you did for Grid.

Example of window using declarative syntax:

HTML:

```
<div id="win" data-role="window"
     data-modal="true"
     data-title="Window Title goes here"
     data-width="400"
     data-height="300"
     data-actions="[ 'close', 'refresh', 'maximize', 'minimize' ]">
    <h2>This is the body of the window</h2>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript for initializing all KendoUI widgets using declarative syntax:

```
kendo.init("body");
```

If from there on you need to explicitly access this widget you can do it by:

```
var my_win = $("#win").data("kendoWindow");
// now you can do things like
my_win.open();
my_win.close();
my_win.center().open();
...
```

Comment: Thank you, OnaBai. How would I refer to it in code and control the open/close of the window in code?

Comment: Alright, I was clearly over-thinking the issue. Now this seems obvious and I added a little snippet to your answer. Thanks a ton for all of your help!

Comment: I don't see my edit now. It was just `var kendoWindow = $("#win").data("kendoWindow");`

Comment: It was rejected (not me) because it was considered more suitable as comment as an edition. Let me include it.

Comment: Thank you. That was really what I was getting at in my question. I knew how to declare it, I was just over-thinking how to get a handle on it in JS once it was declared. As usual, you are awesome.